# Перекомпиляция библиотеки C++ под Windows

Tags: c++, linux, dll, c++builder

Есть исходники библиотеки С++ [С++ исходники библиотеки](https://proj.org/download.html#download)

но эти исходники созданы в неизвестной мне среде и вроде для Linux. С помощью Visual Studio открыть данный проект не получается - нет файла sln.

Можно ли как-то скомпилировать данную библиотеку для Windows? Если да, то как?

Сам С++ не знаю, но мне нужна эта библиотека для проекта C# под Windows.

Comment: там есть cmake файл вроде, но качать больше 550 мб данных, что бы просто это посмотреть как то не хочется. Но там есть pdf,  в котором описан способ установки под винду

Comment: А что вам помешало воспользоваться официальной документацией по использованию этого проекта под Windows?

Comment: Под VS есть возможность создать с++ windows dll - создаём пустой проэкт, закрываем, перетираем все файлы - sln-ка есть, открываем проэкт, добавляем в ветку проэкта все файлы проэкта. Собираем. Если не собирается - смотрим ошибки, если их нельзя устранить быстро -  то тогда прийдётся установить ту среду для которой исходники и собрать под ней. А там - всёравно веселье - на выходе что так что так получаете dll, и занимаетесь прописыванием функций структур в с# для импорта из dll нужных функций.

Comment: Мне нужна не инсталляция, а сборка из этих исходников библиотеки для Windows

Comment: там есть cmake, оно умеет нагенерировать, если такой вариант задуман. @nick_n_a - `s/проэкт/проект/gi`

Comment: Так dll - это и есть сборка.

Comment: Там же в pdf на 34й странице вроде как описано, как собрать под Windows из исходников...

Comment: ага, так надо было ещё и страницу в pdf привести...

Comment: https://proj.org/install.html#cmake

Comment: да, спасибо, ссылка на инструкцию помогла, но правда пересобрав таким образом не получается запустить скомпилированный exe файл - говорит что система не обнаружила библиотеку tiff.dll, но это уже другая проблема

Answer (score 1):

там же на странице проекта: https://proj.org/install.html
описана сборка с помощью CMake

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]